# Is it posible to have something under ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I can't create layout in which I will have

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <ExpandableListView/>
    <Button/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In general I am not able to construct a layout with widget under ExpandableListView, is it possible?

**[edit]**

Now I have another problem. Currently I have something like this:

```
---------------------
|  some text which  |
| could be dragable |
|-------------------|
|ExpandableList  [|]|
|  - item1        | |
|  - item2        | |
|  - item3        | |
|  - item4        | |
|  - item5        | |
|-------------------| 
| [button] [button] |
---------------------
```

I can scroll my expandable list view

```
---------------------
|  some text which  |
| could be dragable |
|-------------------|
|  - item4        | |
|  - item5        | |
|  - item6        | |
|  - item7        | |
|  - item8        | |
|  - item9       [|]|
|-------------------| 
| [button] [button] |
---------------------
```

but in landscape

```
------------------------------|
|   some text which could be  |
|          dragable           |   
|-----------------------------|
|-----------------------------| 
|      [button][button]       |
-------------------------------
```

i don't have place for extendable list view. What I should to achieve completely scrollable results?

Comment: i have already told you in answer that you should put the xml-layout you have done so far, without it how can we come to know whats are the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
is it possible?
```

Yes, it is possible, we can put any widgets (button or textview) at above or below of expandable listview.

It is better that you post the code that you are using for creating a layout. so we will come to know the exact problem easily.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ExpandableListView 
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ExpandableListView>

    <Button 
                android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"            
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <ExpandableListView <!-- ...--> android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- ...-->  /> is a key! Thanks! :)

Comment: @noisy i thought once to point it to you regarding "Wrap_content"